# Android Firebase - Removing a single value from a list

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this Firebase database (the list was created by the `push()` method):

[image]

I want to remove only "Place 1".

I tried the following code, but it deletes the entire "Restaurants" node...

```
databaseReference.child("Restaurants").orderByValue().equalTo("Place 1")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
    }

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

**How do I remove only "Place 1"?**

Answer (score 1):

You are using `databaseReference.child("Restaurant")` as a base reference. Please note that `orderByValue()` does not change the reference, only filter the values. In short, `dataSnapshot` object produced by `onDataChange()` will always point to your reference.

You should do it like this:

```
... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // dataSnapshot object will point at "Restaurant"
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // snapshot object is every child of "Restaurant" that match the filter
        snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

TRY This:

```
    databaseReference.child("Restaurants").orderByValue().equalTo("Place 1")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue(); //used this
}

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```